# Null pointer and pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Is there a way to stop the while loop below from iterating after surpassing 40? I am trying to replicate the linked list concept of iterating while `NULL` pointer is not found.

```
int main() {
    int* arr = new int[4]{ 10,20,30,40 };
    //for(int i=0; i<4; ++i) -- works fine
    while (arr) {
        cout << *(arr++) << endl;
    }
        
    delete[] arr; // Free allocated memory
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pointers don't become NULL when they reach the end of the array. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: (arr+4) is NOT NULL. You may try to `std::cout<< (arr++)` and check what you get.

Comment: The linked list concept applies to, well, linked lists. Dynamic array is a bad smell in modern C++. You want a `std::vector`.

Comment: `int count = 4;  while(count--) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there are to stop the while loop below from iterating after surpassing 40

There are two ways to stop the loop: Cause the condition to become false, or jump out of the loop (break, goto, return, throw, etc.). Your loop doesn't do either.

Your condition is `arr` which is false only if the pointer points to null. You never assign null to `arr`, so it is never null.

---

> I am trying to replicate the linked list concept

Linked list concepts do not generally apply to things that aren't linked lists. Arrays are not linked lists.

Answer (score 1):

Because `arr` is placed in a contiguous memory, you will never get a NULL value of memory address AFTER `arr`.

You may try [following code](https://godbolt.org/z/zPzc3e) on online compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int* arr = new int[4]{ 10,20,30,40 };
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i){
        std::cout << *(arr++) << std::endl;
        std::cout << arr << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "NULL is " << (int*)NULL; // NULL mostly stands for 0.
    return 0;
}
```

Output might be something like this:

```
10    
0x182de74    
20    
0x182de78    
30    
0x182de7c    
40    
0x182de80    
NULL is 0
```

Why does linkedlist works? Because linkedlist stores data in non-contiguous memory and `next()` would give you `NULL` as a sign of the end of a list.

Also you might need a fundamental book of C++.

Here's the [booklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

Use a reserved value such as zero and append it to the end of the array, just like with an old C string. This is called a sentinel element.

```cpp
int* arr = new int[4]{ 10,20,30,40,0 };
while (*arr) {
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

int[4] is a C array. Instead, Use C++ std::array and its iterator:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() // Print all items
{
    std::array<int, 4> arr{ 10, 20, 30, 40 };

    for (auto i : arr)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() // Print until the 1st 0 item
{
    std::array<int, 6> arr{ 10, 20, 30, 40, 0, 0 };

    for (auto i : arr) {
        if (i == 0)
            break;
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```